# How to call initWith... in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a an objective-c class `(RDAlertView)` which create an Alert (UIAlertView for ios < 8 and UIAlertController for ios >=8 )

Here is the code in Objective-C:

```
RDAlertView* alert = [[RDAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification" 
                                                message:@"message" 
                                             completion:completion:^(NSInteger buttonIndex, NSInteger cancelButtonIndex, NSArray *textflieds) { } 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
```

My question is: How to call this in Swift without any change in my class (if possible)?

Here is a link for the sample project : https://bitbucket.org/ejanowski/rdalertview-issue

Comment: Found it, swift seem to don't manage NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION. Thanks to Dharmesh Kheni and James Webster for their help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
var alert = RDAlertView(title: "Notification", message: "message", completion: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: nil)
alert.show()
```

Hope It will help.

Comment: I have this error : "Extra argument 'title' in call"

Answer (score 1):

These methods are treated like constructors. You can call them like this:

```
var alert = RDAlertView("notification", message:"message", completion:nil, cancelButtonTitle:"Cancel", otherButtonTitles:nil)
alert.show()
```

<sub>**Caveat: written without an IDE, careful of syntax errors / typos**</sub>

Comment: This give me an error : "Extra argument in call"
var alert = RDAlertView("notification", message:"test messafe", completion:nil, cancelButtonTitle:"cancel", otherButtonTitles:nil)
            alert.show()

Comment: It might require that the first element has it's label. Try adding: "title:"

Comment: "Extra argument 'title' in call", may by it's the completion block ? I'm new in swift :s

Comment: I'm quite new too :P Since the syntax is a bit new to me, I let autocomplete do some of the work. I type `RDAlertView(`, then tap enter so that most of the syntax is done for me

Comment: Yes but xCode does not make the autocomplete, it just suggest RDAlertView()...
Even the ctrl + space suggest only the default initializer.

Comment: Ah this could be the issue. Do you have your bridging header set up correctly?

Comment: Hum i think, the "Bridging-Header.h" file have this line : #import "RDAlertView.h"
and Objective-c Bridging Header is set with correct file

Comment: However, the bridge file is not in the same level of folders hierachy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77498/discussion-between-ejanowski-and-james-webster).

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 8.

You can show an alert with this code:

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "test", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The OP isn't using UIAlertView, they are using a custom implementation

Comment: Which is based on UIAlertView. Which is deprecated in iOS 8.

Comment: Read correctly the question..... is based on UIAlertView only for ios < 8, else it's an UIAlertController... So this is definitely not a good answer.

Comment: @Fogmeister, Adeel, sorry but this answer remains wrong. You wrongly assume that RDAlertView is based on UIAlertView. The OP clarifies this in the question

Comment: @AdeelAhmed You should delete this answer if you know it's wrong. :)

Comment: @EricD. The answer isn't completely wrong.  It (nearly) correctly shows how to invoke the initialiser from within Swift, even if it is using the wrong class name.  It just needs some editing.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView.showWithTitle("Hello", message: "Hello World", cancelButtonTitle: "Okay") { alertView, buttonIndex in

// Do something when the alert view is clicked

let anAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Choice", message: "Pick one", cancelButtonTitle: "No", otherButtonTitles: "Yes", "Maybe")

anAlertView.showWithCompletion { alertView, buttonIndex in

switch buttonIndex
{
   case 1: println("Yes")
   case 2: println("Maybe")
   default: println("No")
}
}
```