# How to initialize Text to Speech object from Nuance SpeechKit in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, initialization, text-to-speech

There is plenty of documentation on how to do Text to Speech with Nuance´s SpeechKit framework in ObjectiveC. In fact, it is quite easy:

```
self.vocalizer = [[SKVocalizer alloc] initWithLanguage:@"en_US" delegate:self];
```

I want to do the same thing with Swift language:

```
self.vocalizer=SKVocalizer.initWithLanguage("en_US",delegate:self)
```

The problem is that .initWithLanguage does not exist, and I can´t find which equivalent method to use. 
What have I tried?:
I have searched for a method with the same, or similar parameters, with no success. (I might be blind or too burnt to see it)
I CMD+clicked the SKVocalizer object to open its header file and I found this:

```
@interface SKVocalizer : NSObject
- (id)initWithLanguage:(NSString *)language delegate:(id <SKVocalizerDelegate>)delegate;
```

However, this method does not seem to be visible/accessible from the code.

Does anyone who has done TTS with Nuance lend me some help? Thanks!

Comment: Most probably: `self.vocalizer = SKVocalizer(language: "en_US", delegate: self)` . Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163783/how-to-call-initwith-in-swift. – All that is documented in Apple's "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C".

Comment: Thanks!!! I am just an android developer intruding into swift, so I am an apple noob. Put it as an answer and I will give you that green tick!